# How to set StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER for KafkaUtils.createDirectStream?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I wanted to set `StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER` in my Spark Streaming application hoping to prevent a `MetadataFetchFailedException`.

I am not sure where I should pass `StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK` as it seems like `createDirectStream` doesn't allow to pass that parameter.

```
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
  ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
```

Full Error:

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 0
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:456)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.getMapSizesByExecutorId(MapOutputTracker.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleReader.read(HashShuffleReader.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Why do you think setting the storage level could help? A `MetadataFetchFailedException` says that your Spark executors may have got lost or have been under heavy GC.

Answer (score 1):

Use [persist](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream@persist(level:org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel):org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[T]) before you start your `StreamingContext` (and hence the Spark Streaming application):

```
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER
dstream.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
```

That however may lead to the following exception so you should first transform the dstream *somehow*, e.g. `map`, to get a `DStream` of serializable objects.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1.0 in stage 21.0 (TID 29) had a not serializable result: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord, value: ConsumerRecord(topic = topic1, partition = 0, offset = 0, CreateTime = 1482512625196, checksum = 1892285426, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 11, key = null, value = hello world))
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1456)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1444)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1443)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1443)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1671)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1626)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1615)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2015)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2036)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1353)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1326)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$print$2$$anonfun$foreachFunc$3$1.apply(DStream.scala:735)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$print$2$$anonfun$foreachFunc$3$1.apply(DStream.scala:734)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:255)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:254)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use ReceiverLauncher.launch  to generate DStreams from Kafka. Please find the below sample code to set the Storage Level for streaming data from kafka.

`Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("zookeeper.hosts", "x.x.x.x");
    props.put("zookeeper.port", "2181");
    props.put("zookeeper.broker.path", "/brokers");
    props.put("kafka.topic", "some-topic");
    props.put("kafka.consumer.id", "12345");

    props.put("zookeeper.consumer.connection", "x.x.x.x:2181");
    props.put("zookeeper.consumer.path", "/consumer-path");
    //Optional Properties
    props.put("consumer.forcefromstart", "true");
    props.put("consumer.fetchsizebytes", "1048576");
    props.put("consumer.fillfreqms", "250");
    props.put("consumer.backpressure.enabled", "true");`

```
`SparkConf _sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaReceiver")
        .set("spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable", "false");;

JavaStreamingContext jsc = new JavaStreamingContext(_sparkConf,
        new Duration(5000));

//Specify number of Receivers you need. 
//It should be less than or equal to number of Partitions of your topic

int numberOfReceivers = 3;

JavaDStream<MessageAndMetadata> unionStreams = ReceiverLauncher.launch(jsc, props, numberOfReceivers,StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());

unionStreams
        .foreachRDD(new Function2<JavaRDD<MessageAndMetadata>, Time, Void>() {

            @Override
            public Void call(JavaRDD<MessageAndMetadata> rdd,
                    Time time) throws Exception {

                System.out.println("Number of records in this Batch is " + rdd.count());
                return null;
            }
        });

jsc.start();
jsc.awaitTermination();`
```